# Trouble binding methods from object to another object

Tags: javascript, function, methods, bind

I'm writing a factory function that is returning a `Repository` instance that is has methods bound to it from another object. Here's an example:

```js
class Repository {
  constructor() {

  }
  performQuery() {
    console.log('Performing query');
  }
}

const repositoryFactory = (methodObj) => {
  let repo = new Repository();
  for (let prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(methodObj)) {
    repo[prop] = methodObj[prop].bind(repo);
  }
  return repo;
}

let newRepo = repositoryFactory({
  doSomething: function() {
    console.log(this);
  },
  doSomethingElse: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
});

newRepo.doSomething();
newRepo.performQuery();
```

newRepo.doSomething should log the Repository instance. It's obvious when it works because the method `performQuery` will be attached. In this example, it is not.

I apologize if there are some syntax errors in there; I have modified the original code slightly to make it more streamlined, but this is exactly how I'm trying to achieve the method binding. Whenever I try to access `this` from inside `doSomething` or `doSomethingElse`, I get `undefined`.

Comment: The code above clearly won't behave that way. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Your code for `repo[prop] = method` is in the same `if` as the throw. Is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry there are several typos. I'm working quickly to get a working sample.

Comment: Beware using method syntax in that object initializer you're passing into `repositoryFactory`, though. Method syntax sets up a link between the method and the object it's defined on (even after you relocate it). Read up on [[HomeObject]] in the spec for details. It mostly doesn't matter other than making the object non-GC-able and making `super` behave oddly in it (if you were to use `super` in those methods). You may want old-fashioned `doSomething: function() { }` instead...

Comment: With that typo fixed -- basically removing the `if` and `throw()` this works as you described.

Comment: I've updated the code to something that can be executed. It looks like `newRepo.doSomething` logs a context without `performQuery`. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You can not bind arrow functions.

Comment: That's just the console.log.  Try calling it. It works.

Comment: Cristy, I do not believe I'm binding to the arrow function, just performing the operation with other methods.

Comment: @Cristy which arrow functions are being (or trying to be) bound?

Comment: Ah Mark_M, looks like you're right. I updated the code to call `performQuery`. I'll investigate the method syntax, as mentioned by T.J. Crowder. Thanks!

Comment: @Firephp: To be clear, in the above, you could use method syntax and it would be okay. But they would retain a reference to their original object. This would only really be apparent if they used `super`. Anyway, looks like it was a misunderstanding, probably best to delete the question. Happy coding!